# Difference between Matlab spectrogram and matplotlib specgram?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, spectrogram

I am trying to incorporate a preexisting spectrogram from Matlab into my python code, using Matplotlib. However, when I enter the window value, there is an issue: in Matlab, the value is a scalar, but Matplotlib requires a vector. Why is this so?

Comment: You have to convert your scalar values to vector by array. Numpy could help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are just organized differently.

In matplotlib, the window size is specified using the `NFFT` argument. The `window` argument, on the other hand, is *only* for specifying the window itself, rather than the size.  So, like MATLAB, the `window` argument accepts a vector.  However, unlike MATLAB, it also accepts a function that should take an arbitrary-length vector and return another vector of the same size.  This allows you to use functions for windows instead of just vectors.

So to put it in MATLAB terms, the MATLAB `window` argument is split into the `window` and `NFFT` arguments in matplotlib, while the MATLAB `NFFT` argument is equivalent to the matplotlib `pad_to` argument.

As for the reason, specifying the window and window size independently allows you to use a function as the argument for `window` (which, in fact, is the default).  This is impossible with the MATLAB arguments.

In Python, functions are first-class objects, which isn't the case in MATLAB.  So it tends to be much more common to use functions as arguments to other functions in Python compared to MATLAB.  Python also allows you to specify arguments by name, something MATLAB really doesn't.  So in MATLAB it is much more common to have arguments that do different things depending on the inputs, while similar functions in Python tend to split those into multiple independent arguments.

Comment: Does the Fs correlate? I notice that the Fs on matplotlib affects the x axis, too (setting my Fs to 2^-1 or 2^-10 didn't change the image, only both of the scales)

Comment: `Fs` is the sampling frequency, which determines the spacing of the time points and the frequencies.  I would be surprised if Fs in the MATLAB version *didn't* change both the X (time) and Y (frequency) axes.

Comment: How would I zoom in on the lower frequencies, and cut out the higher up ones?

Comment: You can just change the Y limit.

Comment: Not to be dense, but how do I do that?

Comment: It is all in the documentation.  Either `plt.ylim` or `ax.set_ylim` if you have access to the `axes` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help- everything you suggested worked, and has solved issues I have been having for awhile! :)

Answer (score 1):

The value in Matlab is a scalar as it represents the size of the window, and Matlab uses a Hamming window by default. The Window argument also accepts a vector, so you can pass in any windowing function you want.

Comment: Is there a way to specify window size in matplotlib?

Comment: @JoeBernstein: As I said in my answer, use, the `NFFT` argument.

Comment: @JoeBernstein, yes as @TheBlackCat said, you could use the `NFFT` argument. Also, `matplotlib` uses a default of Hann window, so not passing anything to this argument will result in your data being multiplied with a Hann window before being analysed. If you want to change that, you can use the built-in functions which will create windows in the same size of your input data. Look here for more info: http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram